# How can I get value from subscribe?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I tried to do this, but it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated thanks!

```
    export class OuterClass {
    let isEffectiveUrl = (url:string) => {
            let tmpRes:boolean
            this.http.get(url).subscribe((result) => {
                  tmpRes = Object.keys(result).length > 0;
                });
            return tmpRes;
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `isEffectiveUrl` to be a function, not the resulting evaluation.  One way to do this would create a local variable and then execute your `http.get` within a function or one of your lifecycle hooks.

e.g.

```js
export class OuterClass {

  isEffectiveUrl: boolean = false;

  testUrl(url: string): void {
    this.http.get(url).subscribe((result) => {
      this.isEffectiveUrl = Object.keys(result).length > 0;
    });
  }

}
```

Just remember, this is a reactive model.  So what's being run in the subscribe block is asynchronous.